# Adding a picture to CV

Tags: graphics, longtable

I have the following basic code for my CV

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    left = 1.5cm, 
    right = 1.5cm, 
    top = 3cm, 
    bottom = 3cm
]{geometry}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$-$}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
%Manipulation of headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    %Clear fields
    \fancyhf{}
    %Page numbering in footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    %Separation line header and footer
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\llap{$-$}}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\begin{document}
%Title
\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
    \begin{center}
        \Huge \textsc{Curriculum Vitae}
    \end{center}
    \hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize 
    \let\endtitlepage\relax
\end{titlepage}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\textbf{\textsc{Personal Information}}\\
\textsc{Name} & asdasdasd\\
\textsc{Date of birth} & asdasdas\\
\textsc{Place of birth} & asdasd\\
\textsc{Marital status} & asdasd\\
\textsc{Address} & asdasddf\\
\textsc{Phone} & erwwedsf\\
\textsc{E-mail} & asdsgfghfghg\\
\textsc{Nationality} & Swiss\\
\textsc{GitHub} & \href{https://github.com/TheGeekGreek}{https://github.com/TheGeekGreek}\\
%\columnbreak
%\vspace*{4cm}
%\columnbreak
%\begin{Figure}
%   \includegraphics[scale = 0.2]{profile_picture.jpg}   
%\end{Figure}
\vspace{2mm}\\
\textbf{Work Experience}\\
10.2013 - today & adasdasdsdfsdf.\\
03.2015 - today & sdffgfgfg.\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

It is something to start with I think. But I have two questions:

- How do I achieve, that the table is on the left and not centered?
- How do I add a picture in the upper right corner as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Well the first question is pretty easy, `longtable` has an optional argument which defines the horizontal position of the table.  Try `\begin{longtable}[l]{ll} ... ` the optional argument can take `l`, `c` or `r` for alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preamble is a little mess.

You can use picture mode for placing the photo where you like it best.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    left = 1.5cm, 
    right = 1.5cm, 
    top = 3cm, 
    bottom = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{array,longtable,picture}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\makebox[0pt][r]{--}}

%Manipulation of headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
%Clear fields
\fancyhf{}
%Page numbering in footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%Separation line header and footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  

\setlength{\LTleft}{2em}
\setlength{\LTright}{\fill}

\begin{document}
%Title
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\noindent % 4cm is the picture's width, -6cm by trial and error
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm,-6cm){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{duck}}
\end{picture}

\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt

\begin{center}
\Huge \textsc{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{center}

\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\textit{Personal Information}\\
\textsc{Name} & asdasdasd\\
\textsc{Date of birth} & asdasdas\\
\textsc{Place of birth} & asdasd\\
\textsc{Marital status} & asdasd\\
\textsc{Address} & asdasddf\\
\textsc{Phone} & erwwedsf\\
\textsc{E-mail} & asdsgfghfghg\\
\textsc{Nationality} & Swiss\\
\textsc{GitHub} & \href{https://github.com/TheGeekGreek}{https://github.com/TheGeekGreek}\\
\textit{Work Experience}\\
10.2013 - today & adasdasdsdfsdf.\\
03.2015 - today & sdffgfgfg.\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

By setting suitably `\LTleft` and `\LTright` (default value `\fill`) you can move horizontally the `longtable`.

Don't use `$-$` for a dash, the right way is `--`; also `\llap` is a risky command, better use `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}`.

There's no need for `titlepage`.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for the preamble, it was a late night's work. I will fix it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The `longtable` environment takes an optional argument which specifies the horizontal alignment.  In your case us `\begin{longtable}[l]{ll} ...` for left alignment.

As for the picture, you could try adding a new column to the table but this is going to be seriously clunky and probably require `multirow`.  Probably this should be avoided.

On the other hand a fairly non-invasive **but overkill** solution would be to load `TikZ`.  Here I have used `tikzpagenodes` which defines nodes at the four corners of the text region, alongisde the TikZ library `calc` to place the picture at a variable distance between the top and bottom.

[image]

Produced with the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    left = 1.5cm, 
    right = 1.5cm, 
    top = 3cm, 
    bottom = 3cm
]{geometry}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$-$}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
%Manipulation of headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    %Clear fields
    \fancyhf{}
    %Page numbering in footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    %Separation line header and footer
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\llap{$-$}}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
%Title
\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt
    \begin{center}
        \Huge \textsc{Curriculum Vitae}
    \end{center}
    \hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize 
    \let\endtitlepage\relax
\end{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [left] at ($(current page text area.north east)!0.2!(current page text area.south east)$) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{longtable}[l]{ll}
\textbf{\textsc{Personal Information}}\\
\textsc{Name} & asdasdasd\\
\textsc{Date of birth} & asdasdas\\
\textsc{Place of birth} & asdasd\\
\textsc{Marital status} & asdasd\\
\textsc{Address} & asdasddf\\
\textsc{Phone} & erwwedsf\\
\textsc{E-mail} & asdsgfghfghg\\
\textsc{Nationality} & Swiss\\
\textsc{GitHub} & \href{https://github.com/TheGeekGreek}{https://github.com/TheGeekGreek}\\
\vspace{2mm}\\
\textbf{Work Experience}\\
10.2013 - today & adasdasdsdfsdf.\\
03.2015 - today & sdffgfgfg.\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Somebody else may well be able to demonstrate a simpler way to add the image without resorting to a large package like `TikZ`.

Comment: Just tested it. Very nice. Thanks a lot. Maybe there is a better way of doing it, but it does its job really well.